# HTML not loaded at once

Tags: html, css, smarty, loading, cumulative-layout-shift

Google report my website is having a big CLS, so I was checking how the website loads.
I've noticed that the CSS is loaded before the HTML is printed out. How is this possible? Shouldn't the HTML document be loaded first, and then loading all the resources?

In my case the problem is in the order of the elements, in my HTML:

- first is the header
- then is the footer
- then is content.

And then the CSS positions the footer to the bottom (all it is because of z-indexes and fixed footer position).

I put network and CPU throttling, and I see it in the inspector, that the HTML document is loading and adding new HTML elements, while the website is already being styled. Is this normal behavior? My website uses Smarty for generating HTML, is it maybe connected?

Comment: Why does your footer come before your content in the HTML document?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds totally normal to me.

Any styles javascript etc in your head will come with a cost.

Your HTML document gets read from top to bottom. Remember that. So things you place in the head will come first.

If you're trying to achieve a seamless load of aesthetics but keep things relatively quick you should read into the above fold & deferred loading.

In essence, this is where you only load critical stuff to get the page to display as intended instantly and leave everything else at the bottom of your HTML to load later ensuring the user has something tangible to see and use fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know that resources are loaded in the order they are written in document, but I was surprised that the HTML is anyway first styled and then print out, after all it's the HTML that is loaded first, even if the styles are in head.

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround I've used for similar cases in the past is to show a full opacity full page loading overlay until all parts of the page have loaded completely.